# citet flat out refusing to work

Tags: natbib

appologies if i get the question format wrong, this is my first post.

so im writing my thesis at the moment, and all of a sudden natbib seems to stop working entirely.  im not sure why, but all of a sudden citet just reverts to bracketed number..

the format i need is that citep appear as bracket numbers, i.e. [1;2;4] etc. and that citet appear as NAME (YEAR), but no matter what i try citet print square bracketed version..

so i tried to create a dummy document with nothing in it, and citet seems to be working the same way.. what am i doing wrong here guys?

```
\title{natbib issue}
\author{
        James
}
\date{\today}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\maketitle


\section{citep}
This is how citep is working\\
...As seen in previous work \citep{bibreference}.
\paragraph{}

should be\\
...As seen in previous work [1].

\section{citet}
This is how citet is working\\
\citet{bibreference} reports that...
\paragraph{}

should be\\
Abbasi et al. (1999) reports that...

\bibliography{paper}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `natbib` is actually working exactly as it should. :-) You're using the `plain` bibliography style, which can only produce numeric-style citation call-outs with `\citet`. I suggest you switch to the `plainnat` bibliography style. For good measure, specify the options `authoryear` and `round` when loading `natbib`.  After the switch, be sure to recompile with LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all effects of this change.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: thanks, that seems to have fixed most of it..  spent days trying to figure out why it was happening..

Comment: thats quite possible. in my build it doesnt appear to show (author?), however, the same issue on my colleagues computer does.